# React native use reload js doesn't work

Tags: react-native

When I modify some js file, then I click the app's reload js button, The view doesn't update, the nodejs server doesn't auto bulid. I must use the 'react-native start' command again.

Comment: I don't think you can get any answer with provided information. Please provide more details such as version info, os, etc. What you have tried ? And if possible provide code info. Does this occur for all projects ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Windows 8, running on android. Was working fine yesterday at another machine. Have tried to run a clean with gradle, no dice.